# OpenLayers with OpenStreetMap Data Extracts (.oms)

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

Since I'm new with OpenLayer I wanted to ask if it is possible to use the OpenStreetMap data extracted in the **.oms** format as the data source for the OpenLayer for offline usage, I checked the [OpenLayer API documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/) and was unable to find the answer to my question.

Comment: You would need to serve it locally as pbf or osm xml.  There are client examples of those, I don't know hat would be required for the backend.

Comment: You could try to download the .osm files via [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) and then serving the tiles locally with [maperativ](http://maperitive.net/), Mapnik or similar. The routing is obviously a differrent cup of tea to the rendering of the map, more info [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing). Greetings to Mindelo, São Vicente

Comment: In case you want to explain your specific setup and details of your project, we can have a talk in the chat-room..